# Resizing my background image to make it a full page background image

Tags: html, background-image

I am trying to create a landing page with a full page background using this image from unsplash. I resized the image to 1200px using MS paint but it still appears zoomed in when I attempt to set it as a background image.

HTML

```HTML
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="text-overlay">
    <h1><span> Nom</span> <span>Nom</span> <span>Nosh</span></h1>
    <h3>Share your thoughts and recipes for short meals and snacks here!</h3>
    <p>Introducing Nom Nom Nosh, your ultimate hub for quick and delectable
       meal ideas! Catering to the fast-paced rhythm of modern life, Nom Nom
       Nosh is a blogging haven where users can seamlessly share their thoughts
       and swap recipes for short, satisfying meals and snacks. Whether you're
       a culinary enthusiast seeking to spice up your snack game or someone in
       search of speedy, flavorful solutions for your daily dining, Nom Nom
       Nosh is here to transform your kitchen into a hub of creativity and
       efficiency!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.background-image {
  background-image    : url(images/chad-montano-eeqbbemH9-c-unsplash.jpg);
  background-size     : cover;
  height              : 100vh;
  background-position : center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use contain instead of cover.
`background-size: contain;` instead of  `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

There is the code if you want the background image for the whole Website:

```
  body {
  
  background-image: url(URL); 
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

There is the code only for the `.background-image`:

```
  .background-image{
  
  background-image: url(URL); 
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```